# "In a surprised way" or "In wonder" or

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adverbs, construction

I ran for her and put my hand on her shoulder and called Sarah (my wife's name), but immediately, I found out that I had mistaken another woman for my wife! When the woman turned around I said: "Sorry! I took you for someone else!"

(**Part 1**) 
The woman looked at me..........

a. with a surprised look 
b. in a surprised way 
c. in wonder

(**Part 2**)

and told me:

a. with a surprised tone 
b. in a surprised way 
c. in wonder

No worries! It happens!

PS. the combination of the two parts, may sound not natural, but I tried to merge two different scenarios to shorten my questions and make a more comprehensive thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, the first two are not natural and the third probably doesn't describe what you mean: according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wonder), when used as a noun, wonder means "surprise **and admiration**". If you were a famous TV star, "in wonder" might therefore be appropriate.

The most natural way of saying this would be

> The woman looked at me **in surprise**.

For the second part, if she says "no worries! It happens!" none of the suggested options really are appropriate. Maybe "unconcerned" would hit the spot.

Comment: Well, how about if we remove "no worries" @JavaLatte? Would it work to say: "she **told me in surprise**" like the first part?

Comment: "It happens!" still sounds like somebody who is no longer surprise. To still sound surprised, she would have to say something like "Surprised, she asked how I could mistake her for somebody else."

Comment: I see. Then could it sound natural if I would have written something like: "The woman **told me in surprise**: you scared me!"?

Comment: "told me **in surprise**" describes her state of mind **while she is talking**, not when you touched her. You may have surprised her when you touched her unexpectedly, but she uses past tense for scare, so she's over being scared, and I guess she's also over being surprised.